# Why the OnWorkflowItemChanged is different between List and document library?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I am doing a workflow for a document library. I put a `OnWorkflowItemChanged`, and I want to get the value of the column which is changed. I use the `workflowProperties.Item["name"]` and use the `afterProperties`. But when I use the `workflowProperties.Item["column name"]`, I still got the original value. When I use the `afterProperties`, it's `NULL`.

Then I make another workflow that is the same as above for a list. I can use the `workflowProperties.Item["column name"]` to get the new value in `OnWorkflowItemChanged`.

Has anyone come across this problem before? Can you give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to mix up *Item* with *ExtendedProperties*. As to why a difference is seen on a List/Document Lib, it might have something to do with versionining or perhaps the internal serialization is different. Anyway, some of my experience is outline below. I hope it may be of use:

Use the GUID (as a Guid object, not a string) to access the *Before* / *After* **ExtendedProperties** field. Using the Display Name in the ExtendedProperties *will not* work. The documentation on it is wrong. You can use SPList.Fields to go from Display Name to Column ID (Guid).

I bind all "Before" to MyWhatever_PreviousProperties and all "After" to MyWhatever_Properties, only accessing MyWhatever_[Previous]Properties *after* the appropriate event(s)).